# Get Value on ReactJS With REST API

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, rest

I have a problem here, I want to get a value called app_uid from the REST API data, but when I get it, it's null or undefined. I don't know what's wrong with my script. Please help.
This is the API fetching script :

```
fetch('https://bpm.********.or.id/api/1.0/********/cases/draft/paged/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    alldraft: responseJson.data,
                });
                this.state.app_uid = (this.state.alldraft.app_uid);
                console.log(this.state.app_uid)
            });
```

In responseJson.data there are 25 data and I want to retrieve just the app_uid from some of the data but still undefined.

Hopefully this problem can be quickly resolved.
Thank you very much

Comment: Why would there be anything wrong with your script? Step 1: determine where the problem is: what do you get if you curl that url directly?

Comment: Also, remember that `this.state.whatever = ...` *will never work*. You're correctly using `setState`, so use a single `this.setState({ alldraft: ..., app_uid: ... })` and never assign values to `this.state` directly (and if your editor didn't warn about that line, probably look into installing an extension that can flag that kind of code error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're now using component class. If so, in order to access to the state you have just set, you have to invoke it via callback as the 2nd parameter of `setState` method as following since it's async:

```
this.setState({
  alldraft: responseJson.data,
}, () => {
  // Now you can access to your state you set
});
```

Comment: Im try but still undefined .
```
this.setState({
                    alldraft: responseJson.data,
                },()=>{
                    console.log(this.state.alldraft.app_uid);
                });
```

Comment: Can I see your entire component to be clearer the context?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://bpm.********.or.id/api/1.0/********/cases/draft/paged/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                 this.setState({ 
                  alldraft: responseJson.data, 
            },()=>{ 
                  console.log(this.state.alldraft.app_uid); }); 
            });
```

Comment: I meant the entire component class instead of just the snippet of fetching data

Comment: Okay, I have sent the full script again

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './DraftPage.css'
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class DraftPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            user_role: '',
            alldraft: [],
            dataSess: [],
            app_uid :'',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }

        fetch('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/extrarest/session-id', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    dataSess: responseJson,
                });
            });

        fetch("https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/extrarest/login-user", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            }
        }).then(result => result.json()).then(resultJSON => {
            this.getUserRole(resultJSON.uid);
        })
        fetch('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/cases/draft/paged/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    alldraft: responseJson.data,
                },()=>{
                    console.log(this.state.alldraft.app_uid);
                });
            });
    }

    getUserRole = (uid) => {
        fetch("https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/user/" + uid, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            }
        }).then(result => result.json()).then(resultJSON => {
            if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_ADMIN") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Administrator' })
            } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_OPERATOR") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Operator' })
            } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_MANAGER") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Manager' })
            }
        })
    }

    alertShow = (app_uid) => {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="background-nya">
                    <div className="header">
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/menu">
                            <p className="headerLabel-fix"> ASIH PUTERA </p>
                        </Link>
                        <p className="headerLabelUser"> {this.state.username} </p>
                        <p className="headerLabelPass"> {this.state.user_role} </p>
                        <img className="userIcon" src={user2} />
                    </div>
                    <p className="titlePage"> DRAFT LIST </p>
                    {
                        this.state.alldraft.map((draft) => {
                            return (
                                <a href={'https://bpm.**********.or.id/**********/en/neoclassic/cases/open?APP_UID=' + this.state.alldraft.app_uid + '&DEL_INDEX=1&action=EDIT&sid=' + this.state.dataSess}>
                                    <div key={draft.app_uid} className="draftList" onClick={this.alertShow}>
                                        <span style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{draft.app_title}</span><br />
                                        <span>{draft.app_pro_title} - {draft.app_tas_title}</span><br />
                                        <span style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'lighter' }}>Sent on: {draft.app_update_date}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default DraftPage;
```

Comment: You implementation looks weird since `state. alldraft ` is supposed to be array but you are now trying to get `console.log(this.state.alldraft.app_uid); `. If the returned data `responseJson.data ` is not an array, the runtime will throw an error of `.map` is not a function instead. You might have to check your returned data first.

Comment: the data returned from responseJson is above sir ^^

Comment: I'm really confused about what's your'e keen to see. You don't have property in the `alldraft `, do you mean to get all `app_uid ` in single object in the array? If so, you have to write like: `this.state.alldraft.map(elem => console.log(elem.app_uid))`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried console.log (this.state.alldraft), 25 data appeared like this :

```
(25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {app_uid: "2751705175f0ea5d683f702095809786", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82120", …}
1: {app_uid: "2560535315f0ea5d683ebf9082898752", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82119", …}
2: {app_uid: "6965122405f0ea5d5ee5ce0097856044", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82118", …}
3: {app_uid: "2751609235f0ea5d5ec9273041039283", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82117", …}
4: {app_uid: "5950924505f0ea5d5ea4fe8022849221", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82116", …}
5: {app_uid: "7882520755f0ea5d5e2dfd9013797694", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82115", …}
6: {app_uid: "4906131685f0ea5d5baa064018324943", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82114", …}
7: {app_uid: "9079509475f0ea5d5b4b858044760223", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82113", …}
8: {app_uid: "6946994065f0ea5d55da763071146842", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82112", …}
9: {app_uid: "7234585045f0ea5d55ac3e0063614631", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82111", …}
10: {app_uid: "9213060695f0ea5d55a8b84070542982", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82110", …}
11: {app_uid: "6764718825f0ea5d558f1e0022719541", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82109", …}
12: {app_uid: "4852230805f0ea5d52736d5095058537", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82108", …}
13: {app_uid: "8878101545f0ea5d4f17385025385203", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82107", …}
14: {app_uid: "9281484365f0ea5d49309d2079642130", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82106", …}
15: {app_uid: "6313089635f0ea5d48f14d2098084700", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82105", …}
16: {app_uid: "5224353565f0ea5d48e8eb9052064657", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82104", …}
17: {app_uid: "6943525755f0ea5d484bc11079593199", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82103", …}
18: {app_uid: "3204339695f0ea5d4630a21069568523", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82102", …}
19: {app_uid: "6119984205f0ea5d4601c48054370215", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82101", …}
20: {app_uid: "7899867515f0ea5d3c08e28061188384", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82100", …}
21: {app_uid: "4696120055f0ea5d3c00d68053641898", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82099", …}
22: {app_uid: "2041053095f0ea5d3bc5973065347943", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82098", …}
23: {app_uid: "3209234405f0ea5d3b91a49003447096", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82097", …}
24: {app_uid: "2536131125f0ea5d398bb04090682374", del_index: "1", usr_uid: "7998870515d3564d07d95b4034621735", previous_usr_uid: "", app_number: "82096", …}
length: 25
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Now all I need is to just take the app_uid value, but why still undefined ..?